# Which object do these threads synchronize on

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor, synchronized

I want to synchronize 3 threads invoked via ExecutorService. How do I ensure that they synchronize on the same object?

Right now I have this code:

```
class Test { 
    executor.submit(new Request(threadNames[i]));
    executor.submit(new Request(threadNames[i]));
    executor.submit(new Request(threadNames[i])); 

    private class Request implements Callable {
        @Override
        public Long call() throws InterruptedException {
            if (threadName.equals("SOMETHING") {
                doSomething();
            } else {
                doSomeOtherThing();
            }
        }
    }

    private synchronized void doSomething() {
    }

    private synchronized void doSomeOtherThing() {
    }

    ...
}
```

One of these threads is responsible for generating a condition and the other 2 act on it.

Comment: The lock used to synchronize `doSomething` and `doSomeOtherThing` will be on the instance of `Test` in which the `Request` was created.  It's hard to tell exactly what's going on, because your  code is incomplete and doesn't work in its current form - the `executor` calls don't make sense where they are shown in the `Test` class

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't get to submit *threads* to the Executor service; you submit *tasks*, which will at some later point be executed on one of the threads in the Executor's thread pool;
2. if one task is a producer and the two others consumers, then it is wrong to submit all three tasks to the Executor. It can easily lead to a deadlock, where a consumer task waits indefinitely for the producer, but the producer can't run because the consumers are occupying all the threads.

Rethink your solution so that the producer task is also responsible for submitting the consumer tasks to the Executor; the tasks can be instantiated with the produced value, so the coordination problem is solved at the outset.

Comment: I understand that we submit tasks to the executor-service. This is my problem statement:
I want to generate all possible interleavings of my API calls invoked by 2 test threads. In order to achieve this, I would like to assign one thread per request where one request is made of many API calls. I want the threads to pause after invoking each method and I want another thread, say a scheduler signalling/deciding which test thread should proceed based on simple permutation.

Comment: I'm currently synchronizing with synchronized methods and wait() and notify() where all 3 threads are submitted to the executor service and am obviously running into a deadlock.

Comment: You do realize that the trickies concurrency issues do not stem from interleaving, but from write visibility issues? If you just want to test interleavings of API calls, a simple sequential execution with any such interleaving is enough. Otherwise, to really test thread safety, any kind of synchronization is out of the question because it introduces *happens-before* relationships which would not normally exist, masking out data race issues.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it. By convention,
>   a thread that needs exclusive and consistent access to an object's
>   fields has to acquire the object's intrinsic lock before accessing
>   them, and then release the intrinsic lock when it's done with them. A
>   thread is said to own the intrinsic lock between the time it has
>   acquired the lock and released the lock.
>
> When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires
>   the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the
>   method returns. The lock release occurs even if the return was caused
>   by an uncaught exception.
>
> You might wonder what happens when a static synchronized method is
>   invoked, since a static method is associated with a class, not an
>   object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the
>   Class object associated with the class. Thus access to class's static
>   fields is controlled by a lock that's distinct from the lock for any
>   instance of the class.

So your methods are usning intrinsic lock from the `Test` object, and yes, as Marko has correctly pointed out, you might get a deadlock.